# Error starting Samba NetBIOS Name Services (nmb) on CentOS 6

Tags: samba, samba4

I am trying to start the nmb service.  It leaves this in the log file and exists:

```
[2013/05/08 14:06:23,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:883(main)
  nmbd version 4.0.0rc4 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2012
[2013/05/08 14:06:23,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:922(main)
  standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
[2013/05/08 14:06:23,  0] ../source3/lib/util_sock.c:1253(create_pipe_sock)
  error creating socket directory /var/run/samba/nmbd: Permission denied
[2013/05/08 14:06:23,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:48(nmbd_init_packet_server)
  ERROR: nb_packet_server_create failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Here is folder:

```
# ls -ldZ /var/run/samba/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:smbd_var_run_t:s0 /var/run/samba/
```

This is odd:

```
# service nmb status
nmbd dead but pid file exists
# ls /var/run/samba/nmbd.pid
ls: cannot access /var/run/samba/nmbd.pid: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

it is selinux bug ,
disable selinux for nmbd :

```
chcon -t unconfined_exec_t /usr/sbin/nmbd
```

or add rule for socket

```
semanage fcontext -a -t nmbd_var_run_t /var/run/samba/nmbd/unexpected
```

Comment: You may be able to improve this answer by adding the exact permission that needs to be granted to make SELinux work without sacrificing security.